# oh no not again - comparing two bowls of petunias - sorry - floats, for equality

Tags: java

> Due to rounding errors, most floating-point numbers end up being
>   slightly imprecise.

https://www.floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

```
public static boolean nearlyEqual(float a, float b, float epsilon) {
        final float absA = Math.abs(a);
        final float absB = Math.abs(b);
        final float diff = Math.abs(a - b);

        if (a == b) { // shortcut, handles infinities
            return true;
        } else if (a == 0 || b == 0 || diff < Float.MIN_NORMAL) {
            // a or b is zero or both are extremely close to it
            // relative error is less meaningful here
            return diff < (epsilon * Float.MIN_NORMAL);
        } else { // use relative error
            return diff / Math.min((absA + absB), Float.MAX_VALUE) < epsilon;
        }
    }
```

What is the universal standard value for `epsilon`, if, for instance, I wanted to hardcode it for an API that anyone could use for comparing any values?

Comment: Why not letting the users of your API decide what Epsilon they need?

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but the difference is meant to be `relative` thus universal?

Comment: I was hoping for an answer elaborating on the values of `Float.MIN_NORMAL` and `Float.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal standard for epsilon because it strongly depends on what you are comparing and for what purpose. Every time you test for near equality of two floating-point numbers you need to consider two things:

- the absolute value of those numbers
- the kind of quantity they represent

For example PI is widely known to be "around 3.14", and that's good enough for most engineering applications but in Mathematics, or in spectral analysis (Astronomy) you need much higher precision.

Even withing the same domain the absolute values of numbers you compare will influence your choice of epsilon. Comparing circumference of Earth in kilometers to `40_000.00` vs distance to the Moon in meters to `384_400_000.00` have completely different tolerance of errors.

Comment: You are completely ignoring the relative difference calculated. Regardless of the massive size or the minute size of the inputs, the relative difference is dependent on the number of significant figures. For astronomers or particle physicists.

Comment: If you already understand that the relative difference is dependent on the number of significant figures how can you expect a universal epsilon? This is what i tried to explain in my answer - there isn't one epsilon because it depends on the values you compare and the domain. Not all comparisons are between numbers with defined significant figures either, unless you want to limits your library's usage to specific scientific applications.

Comment: I've come up with a method to calculate a suitable epsilon, as opposed to trying to find 'one size fits all'.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean nearlyEqual(double a, double b) {
    if (a == b) { 
        return true;
    } else if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        BigDecimal diff = new BigDecimal("" + a)
                .subtract(new BigDecimal("" + b))
                .abs();
        int exponentA = new Double(Math.log10(Math.abs(a))).intValue();
        int exponentB = new Double(Math.log10(Math.abs(b))).intValue();
        int sigFigsA = getSignificantFigs(a);
        int sigFigsB = getSignificantFigs(b);
        BigDecimal epsilon = new BigDecimal("0.1")
                .scaleByPowerOfTen(Math.min(exponentA, exponentB))
                .scaleByPowerOfTen(-1 * Math.max(sigFigsA, sigFigsB));
        return diff.compareTo(epsilon) < 0;
    }
}

public static int getSignificantFigs(double inputDouble) {
    // remove any exponent
    BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal("" + Math.abs(inputDouble))
            .stripTrailingZeros();
    if (input.scale() < 0) {
        int exponent = new Double(
                Math.log10(Math.abs(inputDouble)))
                .intValue();
        input = input.scaleByPowerOfTen(-1 * exponent);
    }
    return input.precision(); 
}
```

And some tests:

```
@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonOnePositiveOneNegative() {
    Assertions.assertFalse(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    1.234E300D,
                    -1.234E300D
            ), "because one's positive and one's negative");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonZeroes() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    0D,
                    0.0D
            ), "zeroes");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonBasicDifferentNumbers() {
    Assertions.assertFalse(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    2.3450D,
                    2345.0D
            ), "typical numbers");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonMassivelyDifferentNumbers() {
    Assertions.assertFalse(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    1.23456789E300D,
                    1.23456789E-300D
            ), "big number vs tiny number");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonHugePositiveNumbers() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    1.23456789E300D,
                    1.23456789E300D
            ), "big number");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonHugePositiveNumbers2() {
    Assertions.assertFalse(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    1.2345678901234E300D,
                    1.2345678901233E300D
            ), "big number");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonHugePositiveNumbers3() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    Double.MAX_VALUE,
                    Double.MAX_VALUE
            ), "big number equals");
    Assertions.assertFalse(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    Double.MAX_VALUE,
                    Double.MAX_VALUE * 0.1
            ), "big number");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonHugeNegativeNumbers() {
    Assertions.assertFalse(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    -1.2345678901234E300D,
                    -1.2345678901233E300D
            ), "big negative numbers");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonTinyPositiveNumbers() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    1.23456789012345E-300D,
                    1.23456789012345E-300D
            ), "tiny number");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonTinyNegativeNumbers() {
    Assertions.assertFalse(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    1.23456789012345E-300D,
                    1.23456789012344E-300D
            ), "tiny number");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonTinyTinyNumbers() {
    Assertions.assertFalse(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    1.5E-322D,
                    1.4E-322D
            ), "tiny tiny number");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonTinyTinyTinyNumbers() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    Double.MIN_NORMAL,
                    Double.MIN_NORMAL
            ), "tiny tiny number");
    Assertions.assertFalse(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    Double.MIN_NORMAL,
                    Double.MIN_NORMAL * 0.1
            ), "tiny tiny numbers not same");
}

@Test
public void testDoubleComparisonThirds() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(
            GeneralUtils.nearlyEqual(
                    1.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333D,
                    1.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333D
            ), "thirds");
}
```

Comment: I'm confused on what are you trying to achieve here. You basically reimplemented equals. Is there any case when different numbers return true, as in "nearly equal"?